# Change file permission:/system/etc/bluetooth/audio.config

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I use a Samsung Dart - SGH-T499 with Android v2.2.2 on it. 
Now I need to edit the /system/etc/bluetooth/audio.config file. For that I rooted  my phone using the SuperOneClickv2.3.3-ShortFuse. And browsed the file-system using Root Explorer. But I am unable to edit the permission of the audio.config. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to ensure that the `/system` directory, as it's a filesystem, is mounted read-write. In the `adb shell` use `-o rw,remount` as parameters to the mount command to do this. First you need to determine what ( hardware / physical / logical ) device that particular filesystem is stored on - use the `mount` command on its own to see the list and select the one which has `/system` as its mount point.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not issue a

```
chmod 777 /system/etc/bluetooth/audio.config
```

...from the adb shell?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, have tried that. But that is not allowed, it says filesystem is read-only.